# Make user download the app updates compulsorily Android

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to publish my first app. There would be updates and new version of this app coming soon. I want to know if there is a way I can make users download the updates/new versions compulsorily. (I have seen many apps doing that.)

Do I have to make any changes in the code for this? If yes, what will be those changes?

Comment: I suppose, _in theory_, you will need a server (even a shared server where you host your website for instance should do just fine) which the app can communicate with. Every time you update your app, check at the app start-up if the current installed version matches the one on the server (and by extension, Google Play). You won't need to upload the  APK on your server. It could be as simple as a _.txt_ file. If they match, start the app. If they don't, display a message and prevent further code from running. As mentioned before, just a theory. But logically, it _should_ work.

Comment: I am not, however, sure, if such an action would be desirable. Android was meant to be open beyond just the OS source. ;-)